# Chromedriver opens the browser with data in address bar and then opens another window for application

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Facing an issue please help regarding chromedriver

I am using chromedriver version 81 with Chrome browser version 81.

When I launch my app via selenium

1. Chrome browser opens up with data in the address bar
2. Then a new window opens up with data in the address bar and the url given by `driver.get` runs on this window.

Please help me how to handle this

Comment: Following is my code

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
 DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j-alternate.xml");
 Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName());
 WebDriver driver;
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
         "src/resources/chromedriver.exe");
 driver = new ChromeDriver();
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 logger.info("Driver Initialized");
 driver.get("https://login.salesforce.com/");

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and provide a detailed explanation of the problem, along with the minimal code necessary to demonstrate the problem and your expected output and any error messages. You can edit your question and add the code and error messages there.